# Concatenate multiple csvs into dataset by looping on date

Tags: r, for-loop, gsub

I have multiple csvs named with start and end of month like this:
Vars200-2014-02-01-2014-02-28.csv

I want to loop through each month reading in the csv and concatenating to a large dataframe. However, I am having trouble getting the read-in statement to work. this is what i have so far:

```
Dossier = NULL
start = as.Date('2014-01-01')
for (i in 0:12) {
date1 = start %m+% months(i)
date2 = start %m+% months(i+1) - 1
dataset = gsub(" ","",paste("D:/Bing Files/Acing/Dossier/Vars200-",date1,"-",date2,".csv"))
Temp = read.csv(file=dataset,head=TRUE,sep=",")
Dossier = rbind(Dossier,Temp)
}
```

I think is might be something to do with the gsub function, however, this was needed as when i put the date in the paste line, they returned with leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for removing leading and trailing spaces.

```
gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)
```